# Probability of winning a 1v1 turn based game

Tags: probability

Me and my enemy each will have a hero with some attributes like hp, damage, critical chance. Each turn we will attack the enemy's hero until one of our hero's hp reduce to zero. The minimum and maximum damage we can cause to our enemy is 80% and 100% of the hero's damage attribute (i.e my hero have 30 damage point, the minimum and maximum damage is 24 and 30). Suppose i attack first. How can i calculate the probability of winning the game based on hp, damage attributes of my hero and enemy's hero? And how can i calculate the probability of winning if i include critical chance (Assume my hero have 10% critical chance, enemy have 5% critical chance)

Comment: Have you tried to use probability trees ? see e.g. https://www.cuemath.com/data/probability-tree-diagram/
It is likely that you will have a large number of branches (since the damage at each step is variable), if so you might have to resort to a Markov matrix.